# How do you verify that an address is related to a private key

Tags: cryptocurrency

This is my first post. My interest for cryptography is exclusively motivated by cryptocurrencies.

My question is:
If I generate some keys, how do I actually verify that the address is indeed associated with that private key (without the need to test a transaction on the blockchain)? Can we apply this for all cryptocurrencies or is that specific to each one of them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i check if a public key match with a private key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/80424/how-can-i-check-if-a-public-key-match-with-a-private-key)

Comment: An address is a specific term that is not part of cryptography. Please indicate the cryptocurrency, and if it is BitCoin, then check out bitcoin.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The currency is ADA. In fact I am more interested in verifying the address than the public key, but yes verifying the public key from the private key is also of an interest to me and the topic you've given me the link to is interesting but it only deals with the public key.

Comment: The calculation of the address will be specific to ADA. That means you require a cryptographer that knows that spec or is willing to look into it. If you include the address calculation then maybe we can answer this more easily. Unfortunately there is no generic cryptocurrency site anymore.